# check the data between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to check if the `OrderID = 2` exist in Table1 and does not exist in Table2 then return 1 or true.

If `OrderID = 2` exist in both table then return 0 or false..

How can that be done in SQL query?

```
Table1
=======
ID | OrderID
1    2
2    2

Table2
======
OrderID | Name
1         A
2         B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
select ID,t1.OrderID, t2.OrderID is null as notinboth
from table1 as t1 left join table2 as t2 using (OrderID);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ID FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.OrderID = Table1.OrderID`

You will either get the id or `null`.

Comment: Yes. Inner join means that there must be a match in both tables. Otherwise you won't get any result. So if the OrderID is available in both tables you will get what you select, otherwise you will get `null`

Comment: Otherwise you will get no row at all, not null.

Comment: no, you get *nothing*, null will be returned by `fetch_row()` or whatever, so you get no ID for the row.

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    case when 
        exists (select * from table1 where orderid = 2) and 
        exists (select * from table2 where orderid = 2) 
    then 0 
    else 1 
    end
```